# MySQL UDF for working with json?

Tags: mysql, json, user-defined-functions, mysql-udf

Are there any good UDFs in MySQL to deal with json data, that supports the ability to retrieve a particular value in json (by dot notation key - EG: json_get('foo.bar.baz')) as well as the ability to set the value of a particular key - EG: json_set('foo.bar.baz', 'value')?

I found http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_json/ - but it seems to only provide the ability to create json data structures from non-json column values, as opposed to interacting with json column values.

Answer (score 0):

This UDF is able to parse JSON and return the value of an attribute:
https://github.com/kazuho/mysql_json

This other one too: https://github.com/webaroo/mysql-json-udf